# refer to data frame column by object consisting only it`s name (function "get" dosent work)

Tags: r

I need to refer to certain column of data frame by referring to an object consisting it`s name. What i have in mind is:

```
obejct1="df$column5"
>object
[1] "df$column5"
```

Basically I need a way to refer for certain column of data frame in same way like writing simply `df$column5` in my console. While referring to whole data frames i used to do that with function `get` like this `get(object1)` hoping it will return me values from column nr 5. However it this case it returns me an error:

```
Error in get(object1) : object 'df$column5' not found
```

I figured out the problem is that `df$column5` is not an object (`df` is) but a "part" of an object. Is there any way or function to achieve desired result?

Comment: You could `parse()` and `eval()` the string but that's generally a very unsafe idea. What exactly is the requirement that you need to satisfy that requires typing in a string like this at the console?

Comment: `object = get("df")$column5` any good?

Comment: I need to make it part of `subset` function like this: `subset(df, evaluate(object1))` so when i use my custom more complex function for subsetting  I simply choose column name of my data set as an argument and it extracts desired column

Answer (score 0):

The package evaluate seems to do what you want : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/evaluate/evaluate.pdf

I ran this code and it worked fine :

```
install.packages("evaluate")
library(evaluate)
df = data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,1))
colnames(df)=c("cl")
evaluate("df$cl")
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with `subset` function so then i try `subset(df, evaluate(object1))` it returns me no rows...